# After visual studio 2012 update Visual Studio can`t create simple file (ostream)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ostream

My code runs in other computers and creates the test.txt file but (after I updated VS2012) I can not see the file. Also when I debug the code there is no problem It moves on like it created the file but in my project file I can not see test.txt

```
/#include iostream,ostream // Included in right way. No problem here

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ofstream output;
    output.open("test.txt", ios::trunc);
    output << "test.";
    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look in the directory where your source code is located.  There should be a `test.txt` there.

Comment: No there why I m asking.

Comment: Make sure `output.is_open()` returns `true`.  If it does the file is somewhere in your project folder.  Also, have you tried using an absolute path to make sure you know where the file is?

Comment: Maybe your antivirus is preventing your program from running.

Comment: The working directory is set in Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Driectory. The default is $(ProjectDir) which should be the location of your project.

Comment: @NathanOliver I checked if output.is_open() is true and It seems like its false so what can be the problem?

Comment: @drescherjm I don`t use antivirus program. Also Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Driectory. The default is $(ProjectDir) >> It is $(ProjectDir) so no problem there.

Comment: It does not really make a lot of sense. I don't know why you have this problem.

Comment: Use File Explorer and search for your file.

Comment: It is very strange that it works in other computers and not in mine.(I directly copy the cpp and header from my project and send it to my other pc and it worked)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah I know. I tried everything still no solution. I will probably start using other programs.

Comment: Maybe you want to investigate your PC. Perhaps it has a virus or some other hardware or software issue.